# Почему выводится именно так

Tags: python, python-3.x

почему в конце иногда выводятся какие-то числа?
даже если я написал что-бы выводилось только сообщение not enough mana[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: вот пример]

```
import random
import numpy as np
stats = []
attributes = 5
print('Stats: ', end='')
for i in range(attributes):
    r = random.randint(60, 80)
    stats.append(r)
print(stats[i], end=' ')
print('\n\t[1] - Strength\
\n\t[2] - Dexterity\
\n\t[3] - Intelligence\
\n\t[4] - Wisdom\
\n\t[5] - Charisma')
select = int(input('Select: '))
select -= 1
stats[select] = stats[select] + random.randint(5, 15)
for i in range(len(stats)):
    if i == stats:
        continue
        stats[i] = stats[i] - random.randint(5, 15)
        print('Stats: ', end='')
for i in range(attributes):
    print(stats[i], end=' ')
fireball = [12, 15, 28, 10, 5]
lightning = [7, 13, 15, 30, 10]
fire_Ward = [20, 23, 14, 6, 17]
silence = [23, 10, 12, 7, 18]
while True:
    player_slills=input("\n\tWhat kind of power to use? \
    \n\t[f] - fireball\
    \n\t[l] - lightning\
    \n\t[s] - silence\
    \n\t[w] - fire_Ward\
    \n\tSelect: ")
    if player_slills=="f":
        for i in range(5):
            if np.array(stats[i]) > np.array(fireball[i]):
                stats[i] = np.array(stats[i]) - np.array(fireball[i])
                print(stats[i], end=' ')
            else:
                print("Not enough mana")
                exit(0)
    elif player_slills=="l":
        for i in range(5):
            if np.array(stats[i]) > np.array(lightning[i]):
                stats[i] = np.array(stats[i]) - np.array(lightning[i])
                print(stats[i], end=' ')
            else:
                print("Not enough mana")
                exit(0)
    elif player_slills=="s":
        for i in range(5):
            if np.array(stats[i]) > np.array(silence[i]):
                stats[i] = np.array(stats[i]) - np.array(silence[i])
                print(stats[i], end=' ')
            else:
                print("Not enough mana")
                exit(0)
    elif player_slills=="w":
        for i in range(5):
            if np.array(stats[i]) > np.array(fire_Ward[i]):
                stats[i] = np.array(stats[i]) - np.array(fire_Ward[i])
                print(stats[i], end=' ')
            else:
                print("Not enough mana")
                exit(0)
    else:
        print ("Error")
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Это потому что не закомментировали строки типа `print(stats[i], end=' ')`.

UPD:

```py
import random
import numpy as np
stats = []
attributes = 5
print('Stats: ', end='')
for i in range(attributes):
    r = random.randint(60, 80)
    stats.append(r)
print(stats[i], end=' ')
print('\n\t[1] - Strength\
\n\t[2] - Dexterity\
\n\t[3] - Intelligence\
\n\t[4] - Wisdom\
\n\t[5] - Charisma')
select = int(input('Select: '))
select -= 1
stats[select] = stats[select] + random.randint(5, 15)
# Смысла в этом цикле нет, поэтому закомментировал
##for i in range(len(stats)):
##    print('i:', i)
##    if i == stats:
##        continue
##        stats[i] = stats[i] - random.randint(5, 15)
##        print('Stats: ', end='')
##for i in range(len(stats)):
##    print(stats[i], end=' ')
print(*stats) # <-----
fireball = [12, 15, 28, 10, 5]
lightning = [7, 13, 15, 30, 10]
fire_Ward = [20, 23, 14, 6, 17]
silence = [23, 10, 12, 7, 18]
while True:
    player_slills=input("\n\tWhat kind of power to use? \
    \n\t[f] - fireball\
    \n\t[l] - lightning\
    \n\t[s] - silence\
    \n\t[w] - fire_Ward\
    \n\tSelect: ")
    if player_slills=="f":
        for i in range(5):
            if np.array(stats[i]) > np.array(fireball[i]):
                stats[i] = np.array(stats[i]) - np.array(fireball[i])
##                print(stats[i], end=' ')
            else:
                print("Not enough mana")
                exit(0)
        print(*stats) # <-----
    elif player_slills=="l":
        for i in range(5):
            if np.array(stats[i]) > np.array(lightning[i]):
                stats[i] = np.array(stats[i]) - np.array(lightning[i])
##                print(stats[i], end=' ')
            else:
                print("Not enough mana")
                exit(0)
        print(*stats) # <-----
    elif player_slills=="s":
        for i in range(5):
            if np.array(stats[i]) > np.array(silence[i]):
                stats[i] = np.array(stats[i]) - np.array(silence[i])
##                print(stats[i], end=' ')
            else:
                print("Not enough mana")
                exit(0)
        print(*stats) # <-----
    elif player_slills=="w":
        for i in range(5):
            if np.array(stats[i]) > np.array(fire_Ward[i]):
                stats[i] = np.array(stats[i]) - np.array(fire_Ward[i])
##                print(stats[i], end=' ')
            else:
                print("Not enough mana")
                exit(0)
        print(*stats) # <-----
    else:
        print ("Error")
        break
```

Comment: тогда не показывается сколько осталось очков

Comment: @Ivanfifan добавил вариант.